# Python Compare datatype of a data file with metadata file

Tags: python

I am trying to compare datatype of all the columns in a CSV file vs a metadata json file.

Metadata json file contains datatype of all the columns of the csv file.

example: if `customer_name` in the json file = `CHAR`, I want to check the datatype of `customer_name` flied in csv is `CHAR`.

I tried using pandas to identify datatype of each CSV columns and compare against json file. but sometime pandas identifies datatype differently. Example: `Customer_phone` field is `CHAR` in json file, but panda identifies it as `INTEGE`. So, is there any better way to do this comparision in python?

Metadata json contains information like below :

```
{
   "DataType": {
    "customer_name": "CHAR",
    "customer_id": "INTEGER",
    "customer_address": "CHAR",
    "customer_phone": "CHAR"
    }
}
```

CSV file data contains:

```
customer_name|customer_id|customer_address|customer_phone
abc|12345|abc street|0001234567
```

Here is the function I have written:

def check_datatype(df, meta_dict):

```
try:

    datatype_issue = False
    
    file_datatype = df.dtypes.to_dict()
    
    # create compare keys from metadata file
    
    compare_keys = [k for k, v in meta_dict['DataType'].items()]
    
        for key in compare_keys:
        
            if file_datatype[key] == 'int64':
            
                file_datatype[key] = 'integer'.upper()
                
            if file_datatype[key] == 'object':
            
                file_datatype[key] = 'char'.upper()
                
            if file_datatype[key] == 'float64':
            
                file_datatype[key] = 'decimal'.upper()
                
        # check if the metadata data type matches with file column datatypes
        
            if file_datatype[key] == meta_dict['DataType'][key].lower():
            
            else:
            
                datatype_issue = True
                
            if not datatype_issue:
            
                print(f"No datatype issue found")
                
        return datatype_issue
        
except Exception as e:

    print(e)
```

Comment: Anything can be converted to CHAR. So even though phone looks numeric, you can treat it as a CHAR that happens to contain only digits.

Comment: Why do you have `Quoted` and `delimiter` in the `DataType` object in the JSON? Those aren't column names, they're attributes of the CSV file as a whole.

Comment: What is the goal? Do you want to check the data integrity?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/roskakori/cutplace) is something that can help you?

Comment: CSV, as a format, *doesn't have data types*. it's just text delimited by a comma (or another delimiter) and newlines.

Comment: @Barmar - I deleted Quoted and delimiter from the example.

Comment: Why do you have double backticks on every line of your script? Did you do this, or is this a new bug in the Stacks Editor?

Comment: @Plagon goal is to ensure whatever datatype mentioned in the json file matches with datatype of csv. Example: if a customer_id in json = Integer, csv should have integer data type for that field.

Comment: @Barmar I removed the backticks. thank you